# Finding the index of variable in a array decoded by json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working of setting up a paid membership function on our wordpress site.
For paying purposes we try to use a greek payment processor and its coresponding API cals using PHP. Up a point I was succesful but I am stuck in a particular point
One of API function that is offered is to retrive a particular orders details using as reference the orderId. My issue is handling the returned output.
The request would be called using:

`GET /api/transactions/?ordercode=175936509216`

And a sample return would be in RAW:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1285
Expires: -1
Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 11:07:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache

{ "ErrorCode" : 0,
  "ErrorText" : null,
  "TimeStamp" : "2015-09-16T14:07:31.4361544+03:00",
  "Transactions" : [ { "Amount" : 20.0,
        "ChannelId" : "d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553",
        "ClearanceDate" : "2015-09-10T01:10:50.71",
        "Commission" : 0.71999999999999997,
        "CreatedBy" : null,
        "CreditCard" : { "CardHolderName" : "Some name",
            "CardType" : { "CardTypeId" : 0,
                "Name" : "VISA"
              },
            "CountryCode" : "US",
            "IssuingBank" : "Demo Bank",
            "Number" : "411111XXXXXX1111",
            "Token" : "B6D3CC438671F16B211D83BBC077FEBD843CBC28"
          },
        "CurrentInstallment" : 0,
        "CustomerTrns" : null,
        "Fee" : 0.0,
        "InsDate" : "2015-09-09T16:15:09.42",
        "IsManualRefund" : false,
        "MerchantId" : "faae4194-7bf3-4b5c-9fc9-ec584397308c",
        "MerchantTrns" : null,
        "Order" : { "ChannelId" : "95d02b56-bace-4608-ad1b-c1a8da705e52",
            "OrderCode" : 491831172603,
            "RequestLang" : "en-US",
            "ResellerId" : null,
            "ResellerSourceCode" : null,
            "SourceCode" : "Default",
            "Tags" : [  ]
          },
        "ParentId" : null,
        "Payment" : { "ChannelId" : "d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553",
            "Email" : "some.email2@some.company.com",
            "FullName" : "Some names",
            "Installments" : 0,
            "Phone" : "6969696969",
            "RecurringSupport" : false
          },
        "ResellerId" : null,
        "ResellerSourceCode" : null,
        "SourceCode" : "Default",
        "StatusId" : "F",
        "TargetPersonId" : null,
        "TotalInstallments" : 0,
        "TransactionId" : "9b7af26e-bba7-4830-8d81-36dfd2bc3f3c",
        "TransactionType" : { "Name" : "ChargeCard",
            "TransactionTypeId" : 5
          }
      } ]
}
```

Wich using the json decode function is converted into a array and using var_dumb function we get the following result :

```
array(4) {
  ["Transactions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(24) {
      ["Fee"]=>
      float(0)
      ["ParentId"]=>
      NULL
      ["Amount"]=>
      float(20)
      ["StatusId"]=>
      string(1) "F"
      ["ChannelId"]=>
      string(36) "d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553"
      ["MerchantId"]=>
      string(36) "faae4194-7bf3-4b5c-9fc9-ec584397308c"
      ["ResellerId"]=>
      NULL
      ["InsDate"]=>
      string(22) "2015-09-09T16:15:09.42"
      ["CreatedBy"]=>
      NULL
      ["SourceCode"]=>
      string(7) "Default"
      ["TransactionId"]=>
      string(36) "9b7af26e-bba7-4830-8d81-36dfd2bc3f3c"
      ["Commission"]=>
      float(0.72)
      ["MerchantTrns"]=>
      NULL
      ["CustomerTrns"]=>
      NULL
      ["IsManualRefund"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["TargetPersonId"]=>
      NULL
      ["TotalInstallments"]=>
      int(0)
      ["CurrentInstallment"]=>
      int(0)
      ["ClearanceDate"]=>
      string(22) "2015-09-10T01:10:50.71"
      ["ResellerSourceCode"]=>
      NULL
      ["Order"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["OrderCode"]=>
        int(491831172603)
        ["ChannelId"]=>
        string(36) "95d02b56-bace-4608-ad1b-c1a8da705e52"
        ["ResellerId"]=>
        NULL
        ["SourceCode"]=>
        string(7) "Default"
        ["Tags"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["RequestLang"]=>
        string(5) "en-US"
        ["ResellerSourceCode"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["Payment"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["Email"]=>
        string(30) "somename@somecompany.com"
        ["Phone"]=>
        string(10) "6969696969"
        ["ChannelId"]=>
        string(36) "d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553"
        ["FullName"]=>
        string(17) "Some Name"
        ["Installments"]=>
        int(0)
        ["RecurringSupport"]=>
        bool(false)
      }
      ["TransactionType"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(10) "ChargeCard"
        ["TransactionTypeId"]=>
        int(5)
      }
      ["CreditCard"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["Token"]=>
        string(40) "B6D3CC438671F16B211D83BBC077FEBD843CBC28"
        ["Number"]=>
        string(16) "411111XXXXXX1111"
        ["CountryCode"]=>
        string(2) "US"
        ["IssuingBank"]=>
        string(9) "Demo Bank"
        ["CardHolderName"]=>
        string(17) "Some Name"
        ["CardType"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["Name"]=>
          string(4) "VISA"
          ["CardTypeId"]=>
          int(0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["ErrorCode"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ErrorText"]=>
  NULL
  ["TimeStamp"]=>
  string(33) "2015-09-16T14:07:31.4361544+03:00"
}
```

The question is how can I find what is the specific index of this array for a particular variable so that can be assigned to an other new variable for further processing . For example if I wanted the contents of the email variable in the payment array , how would I refer it ?
For the moment the API that I working is on the demo - developers part so the data shown here are just dummy data 
addition to the requested comment using the print_r function

```
    Array
    (
    [Transactions] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Fee] => 0
                [ParentId] => 
                [Amount] => 20
                [StatusId] => F
                [ChannelId] => d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553
                [MerchantId] => faae4194-7bf3-4b5c-9fc9-ec584397308c
                [ResellerId] => 
                [InsDate] => 2015-09-09T16:15:09.42
                [CreatedBy] => 
                [SourceCode] => Default
                [TransactionId] => 9b7af26e-bba7-4830-8d81-36dfd2bc3f3c
                [Commission] => 0.72
                [MerchantTrns] => 
                [CustomerTrns] => 
                [IsManualRefund] => 
                [TargetPersonId] => 
                [TotalInstallments] => 0
                [CurrentInstallment] => 0
                [ClearanceDate] => 2015-09-10T01:10:50.71
                [ResellerSourceCode] => 
                [Order] => Array
                    (
                        [OrderCode] => 491831172603
                        [ChannelId] => 95d02b56-bace-4608-ad1b-c1a8da705e52
                        [ResellerId] => 
                        [SourceCode] => Default
                        [Tags] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [RequestLang] => en-US
                        [ResellerSourceCode] => 
                    )

                [Payment] => Array
                    (
                        [Email] => someone@somecompany.com
                        [Phone] => 6969696969
                        [ChannelId] => d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553
                        [FullName] => Some Name
                        [Installments] => 0
                        [RecurringSupport] => 
                    )

                [TransactionType] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => ChargeCard
                        [TransactionTypeId] => 5
                    )

                [CreditCard] => Array
                    (
                        [Token] => B6D3CC438671F16B211D83BBC077FEBD843CBC28
                        [Number] => 411111XXXXXX1111
                        [CountryCode] => US
                        [IssuingBank] => Demo Bank
                        [CardHolderName] => Leonidas leonidas
                        [CardType] => Array
                            (
                                [Name] => VISA
                                [CardTypeId] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

  [ErrorCode] => 0
  [ErrorText] => 
  [TimeStamp] => 2015-09-16T16:15:59.9665031+03:00
 )
```

Comment: Can you try 
    
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($YourArray);
     echo "</pre>";

and pur the output here?

Comment: Original question has been modified and the output included

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out. First of all, decode your json to an array with using second parameter as true in json_decode function.

Then iterate on it with foreach and check if transactions is an array, if it is then iterate on the transactions as transaction one by one and access to fields by name.

```
  $myArray = json_decode('{"Transactions":[{"Fee":0.00,"ParentId":null,"Amount":20.00,"StatusId":"F","ChannelId":"d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553","MerchantId":"faae4194-7bf3-4b5c-9fc9-ec584397308c","ResellerId":null,"InsDate":"2015-09-09T16:15:09.42","CreatedBy":null,"SourceCode":"Default","TransactionId":"9b7af26e-bba7-4830-8d81-36dfd2bc3f3c","Commission":0.72,"MerchantTrns":null,"CustomerTrns":null,"IsManualRefund":false,"TargetPersonId":null,"TotalInstallments":0,"CurrentInstallment":0,"ClearanceDate":"2015-09-10T01:10:50.71","ResellerSourceCode":null,"Order":{"OrderCode":491831172603,"ChannelId":"95d02b56-bace-4608-ad1b-c1a8da705e52","ResellerId":null,"SourceCode":"Default","Tags":[],"RequestLang":"en-US","ResellerSourceCode":null},"Payment":{"Email":"some.email2@some.company.com","Phone":"6969696969","ChannelId":"d84f93ff-8ad0-4d97-a7a3-f187dd667553","FullName":"Some names","Installments":0,"RecurringSupport":false},"TransactionType":{"Name":"ChargeCard","TransactionTypeId":5},"CreditCard":{"Token":"B6D3CC438671F16B211D83BBC077FEBD843CBC28","Number":"411111XXXXXX1111","CountryCode":"US","IssuingBank":"Demo Bank","CardHolderName":"Some name","CardType":{"Name":"VISA","CardTypeId":0}}}],"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorText":null,"TimeStamp":"2015-09-16T14:07:31.4361544+03:00"}',true);
  foreach($myArray as $transactions){   
        if(is_array($transactions))
            foreach($transactions as $transaction){
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($transaction);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "<br>";
            if($transaction['Payment']){
                echo $transaction['Payment']['Email'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Out put is some.email2@some.company.com
Cheers